# Washing your feet when you wake up?

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, parts-of-the-body

So I've heard that we Jews (when waking up) used to first wash their feet and then their hands. But what happen today, don't we wash our feet anymore? Or is that an optional thing? Do some still do it today?

Comment: Where did you hear this? "don't we wash our feet anymore?" Are you asking what common practice is?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeKFkoFFjBI) video has a man washing his feet before washing his hands. But this beit midrash runs according to the most ancient sources, Temani minhagim, and halachic rulings from the Rambam. For sure it is not the common practice among most of today's Jews. They seem to cite many sources for their unusual practices.

Answer (score 8):

The Gemara ([Shabbos 50B](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=50b&format=pdf)) says one should wash his face, hands and legs every day in honor of his Creator.

The Mishna Berura ([OC 4:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.4.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) writes in the name of the Pri Megadim ([A"A 4:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x602)) that nowadays since we don't walk barefoot there is no need to wash one's feet (This reasoning is also given by the [*Noda Biyhudah*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlt-_wro3ZAhUDzIMKHXrFCcgQmhMIpgEwDA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FYechezkel_Landau&usg=AOvVaw1X8Sm8f_wR8Xt0rkmdZ9E3) ([OC 2:140](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A2_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_(%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%90)/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A7%D7%9E))), although the Baal HaTanya ([OC 4:21](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3268366/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-4-Laws-Relating-to-Washing-Hands.htm)) brings this gemara with no comment.